# Touching up the coloring on my American nylon flag

Tags: painting, restoration

Touching up the coloring on my American, nylon flag. What is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Is it faded because of sun or is it other damage? Do you know how it was dyed originally? We don't tend to cover repair to bought items (we focus on _handmade arts and crafts)...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try fabric paint available at a serious art supply store. In Australia, I'd would by [these](http://www.newtownartsupplies.com.au/permaset-fabric-paints/), as they set permanently.

Matching your colours will be difficult, so experiment on a scrap of paper, 
fabric or even a paper plate first. (My experience with plastic paints is that they dry darker.)

Another option is [fabric markers](https://www.bakerross.com.au/giotto-fabric-pens-box-of-48?&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_JDWx8HY4QIVGR4rCh3SoghuEAQYASABEgIj-vD_BwE), although heat setting the ink with an iron would need to be done carefully and on a low heat setting for nylon. Again, test your technique on a scrap of nylon first.